# "abordera-t'il" : est-ce grammaticalement correct ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, inversion

Je suis en train de rédiger un document professionnel. Durant la relecture, un collègue a pointé la phrase suivante comme étant incorrecte :

> Ce document présentera le régime alimentaire des licornes, puis il
> détaillera la politique économique du Swaziland. **Enfin abordera-t'il
> la question de l'appellation des viennoiseries chocolatées.**

**Cette utilisation du verbe aborder est elle incorrecte dans une phrase affirmative ?** Est-ce le cas pour tous les verbes (enfin mangea-t'il ses pâtes, enfin prit'il le bus, enfin eut'il sa réponse...) ?

[Le seul exemple d'utilisation de cette forme que j'ai pu trouver](http://languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8509) semble indiquer que mon collègue à raison, mais j'ai toujours le sentiment que "ça sonne bien" (même si l'apostrophe est assez laide).

Je sais que je pourrais écrire "il abordera enfin" à la place, mais j'aimerais avant confirmer mon erreur.

Comment: La phrase affirmative est incorrecte. Par ailleurs,il faut l'écrire avec deux tirets : `abordera-t-il`

Comment: Les chocolatines ?

Comment: J'enfonce le clou planté par @Toto et al. : dans 'abordera-t-il', le `t` est euphonique sans autre fonction que l'[épenthèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89penth%C3%A8se). L'apostrophe `t’` est utilisée dans la forme contractée du pronom `te`. Ce sont deux entités grammaticales absolument distinctes mais j'ai l'impression qu'on les voit de plus en plus confondues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bien que l'inversion du sujet soit parfois possible (voire obligatoire) quand la phrase commence par un adverbe, la phrase proposée dans la question n'est pas correcte car l'inversion n'est pas possible si cet adverbe est *enfin*. Il faudrait dire :

- Enfin il abordera la question de l'appellation des viennoiseries chocolatées.

Bien que personnellement je trouve qu'*enfin* en position initiale est peu élégant et je préfère dire :

- Il abordera enfin (ou si c'est vraiment la dernière partie du document « pour finir »).

Par contre si tu employais *ainsi* ou *peut-être* l'inversion serait possible :

- Ainsi (peut-être) abordera-t-il la question de l'appellation des viennoiseries chocolatées.

Pour une réponse détaillée sur l'inversion du sujet après un adverbe initial je renvoie à [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/26712/358) déjà présente sur le site.

[Le lien](http://languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=8509) donné dans la question traite du cas particulier de l'incise, ça ne concerne que très peu de verbes (dire, penser, répondre, affirmer, déclarer, etc.). Par exemple :

- Je vais bien, répondit-elle.

Ceci est déjà traité sur French Language dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13343/358). On peut aussi consulter la BDL :  [Citation avec incise](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3249).

Comment: Merci, ça me rassure de voir que je n'avais pas entièrement inventé cette structure.

Comment: @Astrosias Mais attention, comme le dit Toto dans son commentaire, l'apostrophe n'a rien à faire ici !